# Best x values for numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a (non-negative) function `f` which I can easily evaluate for any given value of `x` in the interval `-1 <= x <= 1`. I need to find the first `m` coefficients of its Taylor Series expansion (`m` could easily be as large as 20).  I anticipate doing this with numpy `polyfit` by evaluating `f` at many values of `x`.

I know there are situations where, for example, Chebyshev collocation points are optimal for numerical methods (but that's something I know of rather than something I've worked with), and I'm wondering if something similar may exist for the question I'm looking at.

So my question is are there any particular choices of `x` that provide an optimal fit?

---

**a couple facts about `f`**: it is a probability generating function, meaning that its expansion has all non-negative coefficients, and the coefficients sum to `1` (i.e. `f(1)=1`).

Comment: Despite the fact that eventually you want to solve this with numpy, this is more a math question, is it not? You should probably ask this on math exchange.

Comment: Yes and no - what to do will surely depend on the details of how `polyfit` is implemented.

Comment: Reminds me a little of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPl64xi_ZZA) classical proof. However, from a mathematical point I'd say the closer the points to zero (origin of the Taylor expansion?) the better the coefficients. On the other hand this can be limited by numerical precision, which---moreover---depends on the shape of your graph. I just played with `sin` and putting 15 equidistant points in `[0,1]`,`[0,2]`, and `[0,3]`, making `[0,2]` best compared to known coefficients.

Comment: Thanks @mikuszefski (I used to be on the faculty in the same department as the presenter in that video).